# How to configure write behind with Caffeine cache?

Tags: java, caching, caffeine

I want to use Caffeine for caching and I need to have a write-behind. I want to limit the amount of times I write to the database. The [documentation](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine/wiki/Writer) speaks of *write-back cache* so it should be possible, but there is no example there on how to configure it. I have implemented a `CacheWriter`, but I don't understand how to configure it to for example only call the writer once every 10 seconds (If something changed to the cache ofcourse).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CacheWriter` is an extension point and the documentation describes the use-cases where it may make sense. Those cases are beyond the scope of the library and if implemented instead could have been too rigid.

The writer is called atomically during a normal write operation (but not a computation). This ensures that a sequential order of changes is observed for a given key. For write-behind the writer would add the entry into a queue that is processed asynchronously, e.g. to batch the operations.

When implementing this capability you might want to consider,

- Coalescing the updates (e.g. collect into a `LinkedHashMap`)
- Performing a batch prior to a periodic write-behind if it exceeds a threshold size
- Loading from the write-behind buffer if the operations have not yet been flushed (This avoids an inconsistent view, e.g. due to eviction)
- Handling retrials, rate limiting, and striping depending on the the characteristics of the external resource

**Update:**

Wim Deblauwe provided a nice [example](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine/tree/master/examples/write-behind-rxjava) using RxJava.

Comment: Ah, that was totally not clear. Maybe the first section that has no title can get a title "Usage" and the other 3 titles can be grouped under a new title "Possible use cases". Maybe even with a note that these are things that are possible to implement on top of that `CacheWriter` but are not available in Caffeine. In the end, I went with Hazelcast as they have write-behind out of the box.

Comment: Thanks, I'll improve the documentation then. I think a community extension to offer this capability would be nice. I'd like Caffeine too feel like a library (flexible, small, obvious, focused) to avoid the mistakes many framework authors make. Hopefully it is extensible enough to be used as a building block to handle aspects outside of its scope.